# How can I get string resource in Jetpack composable test

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-testing

We can get the string resource in Composable through stringResource like

```
@Composable
fun Heading(
    @StringRes textResource: Int
) {
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = textResource),
        color = colorBlack,
    )
}
```

But how can we get this string resource in composable test.

```
class HeadingTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    @Test
    fun headingTest() {
        // Start the app
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            AppTheme {
                // In Compose world
                Heading(textResource = R.string.some_text)
            }
        }

        //How can I access string resource here
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(???).assertExists()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Still you can use `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` to get resource in composeapp.

```
    val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
    var string2 = context.resources.getString(R.string.hello_world)
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the ones suggested so far since it allows testing composables in isolation of any specific activity. The only comment here is that InstrumentationRegistry is deprecated. Instead you can use ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() to get the context.

Comment: In some cases this is more convenient to pass around than `ComposeTestRule`

Answer (score 6):

Create compose rule via `createAndroidComposeRule` and then you will be able to access `activity.getString()` method

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

val activity = composeTestRule.activity

@Test
fun testDisplayAndClickable() {
    val home = composeTestRule.activity.getString(R.string.home)
}
```

Comment: Just adding here that, if you're using `createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()` and setting its content like `composeTestRule.setContent { }` from a test function, the `val activity` has to be declared inside the function, after setting the content. Otherwise, you'll get a null pointer exception.

Comment: what if we are using modules and dont have any activity in our module

Comment: Produces "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot run onActivity since Activity has been destroyed already" for some reason.. Maybe because there is also another rule in my test, that conflicts? Namely `@get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but you can do the following:

```kotlin
class HeadingTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    @Test
    fun headingTest() {
        val textId = R.string.some_text
        var string = ""
        // Start the app
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            string = stringResource(id = textId)
            AppTheme {
                // In Compose world
                Heading(textResource = textId)
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(string).assertExists()
    }
}
```